# Is it possible to entirely hide footer navigation option of Safari browser using jQuery-Mobile?

Tags: iphone, jquery-mobile, hide, footer

I have a quick question. I am using jQuery-Mobile for mobile web development. I know how to make fixed position for header and footer but a simple question: is it possible to hide the browser's footer navigation? I mean in iPhone, using safari browser, we have safari's built in footer that has forward, back, bookmark etc tapping options at the bottom. I have my own custom footer for tapping options and I want to use that and hide the safari's built-in tapping options. Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a user adds your site to their home-screen then when they click on the icon to view your website you can force a full-screen UI.

Here is a list of the supported meta tags you can add to your site that will be used when the user adds your site to their home-screen: http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html

## apple-mobile-web-app-capable

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

> If content is set to yes, the web application runs in full-screen
> mode; otherwise, it does not. The default behavior is to use Safari to
> display web content. You can determine whether a webpage is displayed
> in full-screen mode using the window.navigator.standalone read-only
> Boolean JavaScript property.
>
> Available in iOS 2.1 and later.